# How to store exact precision value in java and hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

User input is: **44.4**

While storing into database its converting to: 44.40000153

Database Data Type is : **float** and Length is : **20,8**

Here I want to store exactly 44.4

I don't want to change database design.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `float` then. Use `number(10,5)` (or however many digits you need) in the database and `BigDecimal` in Java.

`BigDecimal` gives you an unlimited number of digits, but in the database there are limits to what can be stored. Usually something like 38 digits (i.e. usually enough).

Comment: Then you cannot store `44.4` precisely in that column. You could try to round it back before displaying using a `NumberFormat`.

Comment: One option to store arbitrarily precise values in the database is to store them as strings and convert to/from `BigDecimal`. You lose the ability to perform numeric operations on them in queries though.

Answer (score 1):

**`field float(20,1)`**

You can try using above change.

Make it **`20,1`**

I had tried same as below

```
create table abc(field float(20,1));
insert into abc value(44.4);
select * from abc
```

Or, if you are unable to change database then go with below query

**`select cast(field as decimal(10,1)) from abc;`**

Here I had used [**`CAST`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

And it shows me your expected result.